# Inverse and log link give opposite results in Gamma GLM

Tags: r, regression, statistical-significance, glmmtmb

I'm fitting a Gamma GLM using `glmmTMB` and noticed that choosing `link = "log"` or `link = "inverse"` results in parameter estimates that are significant in opposite directions.

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix? See `dput` below for data

```
x = structure(list(var1 = c(0.252214238219584, 0.392393931685829, 
0.144745633176505, 0.308126587339902, 0.328376189036203, 0.448369984805282, 
0.936598306354151, 0.193636718064947, 0.768749218283505, 0.357832847421775, 
1.47491885344668, 0.155497713156763, 1.12115316768318, 0.837676043037134, 
1.53503317163688, 0.754183867269509, 0.548106539601555), var2 = c(0.70647579687333, 
1.04473861807629, 1.84568187850562, 1.38745693126706, 1.60662551723233, 
0.736254217923361, -0.267283783737272, 0.0456167380411754, -0.521883531241859, 
-0.535681010177461, -0.864279209771702, -0.590462314402458, -0.921734676751276, 
-0.946300165941173, -0.90930751152499, -0.856192457022951, -0.959725037348014
), response = c(0.593509186563276, 0.903311661944313, 1.70259114856063, 
1.59830476093735, 1.00786737377972, 0.587735943445756, 0.902085128305588, 
0.606081620834813, 0.602025472816966, 0.580752729893258, 0.359975287530704, 
0.398756072099323, 0.420545404483222, 0.601250102543585, 1.0150031158697, 
0.316484299162052, 0.358969033462004)), row.names = c(NA, -17L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(glmmTMB)
library(tibble)
m_inverse <- glmmTMB(response ~ 
            var1 + 
            var2 , 
         family = Gamma(link = "inverse"),
         data = x)
summary(m_inverse)

m_log <- glmmTMB(response ~ 
                       var1 + 
                       var2 , 
                     family = Gamma(link = "log"),
                     data = x)
summary(m_log)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't an error. The GLM is doing exactly what you're telling it to do.

The log link is an **increasing** function of the linear predictor, while the inverse link is a **decreasing** function of the linear predictor.

Recall a GLM "links" the linear predictor $X\beta$ to the mean $E[Y]$ via the link function $g(\cdot)$:

$$g(E[Y]) = X\beta$$

Speaking generally

- If your model has a log link ($\log(E[Y]) = X\beta \rightarrow E[Y] = \exp(X\beta)$), then a predictor $x$ associated with an increase in the mean, will have a positive $\beta$.
- If your model has an inverse link ($1/E[Y] = X\beta \rightarrow E[Y] = 1/(X\beta)$), then a predictor $x$ associated with an increase in the mean, will have a negative $\beta$.